# Merge two reports that each one contains 3 subReports into one single report in Crystal reports (C#)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, subreport

I have two reports `ReportA` and `ReportB` :

1. `ReportA` contain 3 SubReports : `SubReportA1`, `SubReportA2`, `SubReportA3`
2. `ReportB` contain 3 SubReports : `SubReportB1`, `SubReportB2`, `SubReportB3`

I wanna to combine `ReportA` and `ReportB` into horizontal single file :

[image]

**More Info : the 6 reports must be placed in `one single section`**

the issue is that `SubReportX` cannot support another subReports

Comment: what is the issue? have you tried placing the reports side by side?

Comment: "subreportX" cannot support other subReports : this is the issue !

Comment: Ohh sorry didn't see that.... instead of sub report inside a sub report... you can place 6 sub reports inside a single main report and check what is the result

Comment: if i   place 6 sub reports inside a single main report  i get overlapping between the rapports

Comment: You can export the reports to PDFs and join (merge) them in one file. This is the only way I know. What are you going to do with the 2 reports ? View, print , send by e-mail ?

Comment: I don't think those will overlap you can place in different sections and also you can limit the width of the sub reports.

Comment: @Lan yeah i want to View,Print and e-mail

Comment: @Siva if i use many sections i will not have the six reports on the same level i f you understand what i mean ?

Comment: @Lan how can'i merge two reports ?

Comment: you just have to insert as subreport the SubReportX and SubReportY

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own application , which will export each of the reports to a PDF and then get the 2 PDFs and merge them in a single PDF file. Then you can show this file on the screen, print it or e-mail it. 
There are tools on the market that can do this, so you will need just to add the reports and configure a task to export and merge them. Here is a sample video showing the process of merging 2 files: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_CreateJob.aspx
The tool from this video has a free version available from this link: http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/CommunityEdition.aspx. So, no purchase is necessary and this seems the cheapest way to handle your scenario. Creating your own application will be much more expensive. There might be other tools on the market that can do this too.

Comment: Okéy that's mean there is no solution Using Crystal Report